# how to implement this sliding navigation menu?

Tags: android, android-xml

I'm trying to replicate the following sliding navigation menu functionality (the one with "TOP STORIES", "World", "U.S" etc.) with no luck so far. 
I'm feeling there is an obvious way to achieve this, as I'm constantly seeing this in many apps. Is it based on a library shipped with Android? Any starting point or materials used to achieve this are welcomed.
Keep in mind, I don't care about the design/xmls, just the implementation logic.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is nothing but a HorizontalScrollView that contains child views.